# Instantiate multiple classes in php

Tags: php, class, object, instantiation

Is there a better way to instantiate classes instead in a 1-2-3 sequence like below? So I am looking to use a method to load multiple classes through a single line such as:

```
main::instantiateClasses(array("class1", "class2", "class3"));
```

etc.

instead of:

```
$_class1 = new class1();
$_class2= new class2();
$_class3 = new class3();
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Strange question. Would you provide use-case?

Comment: probably you want to have access to the single instances...it can helps if you can provide a use case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why would you do that but try that:

```
public static function instantiateClasses($classes) {
    $count = count($classes) ;

    for($var= 1, $class=0; $var < $count + 1 && $class < $count; $var++, $class++) {
    $class_name = '$_class'.$var.'';
    $$class_name = new $classes[$class] ;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm new to php but not sure why it's a strange question. Just want a more neater and faster way to write it. Thanks for this but my class names don't necessarily have to be named class1 class 2 in fact they named by their module name. "user" class or "profile" class etc. I believe this function only works with the class naming convention 1-2-3?